# How to search values in excel and assigned a particular value based on logic (Based on RIGHT, IF, OR condition)

Tags: excel-formula

Trying to extract the values from the right side (single digit) of the ID column and based on that assigning `"A","B","C",""`

I have tried with the below logic, but not getting the expected result. Can anyone suggest me in this?

```
=IF(RIGHT(A2,1)=OR(1,2,6),"A",IF(OR(3,7,9),"B",IF(OR(4,8,0),"C",IF(5,"D",""))))
```

**Excel Table:**

```
ID    Value
AB1ZX0  C
BC5SD2  A
FR3WDX  
CA4EG7  B
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple issues with your original try:

1. Since the cells are text based, you need quotes around the number you are testing (`...="1"` instead of `...=1`).
2. You need to reference what you are testing (the `RIGHT(A2,1)`) each time you use `IF`.
3. You can not use `OR` like that; it's return is boolean so you would need to do something like `=IF(OR(RIGHT(A2,1)="1", RIGHT(A2,1)="2", RIGHT(A2,1)="6"), "A", ...` to make it work.

Instead, the below should do the trick, though it is a little messy and verbose:

```
=CONCAT(IF(RIGHT(A5,1)={"1","2","6"}, "A",
IF(RIGHT(A5,1)={"3","7","9"}, "B",
IF(RIGHT(A5,1)={"4","8","0"}, "C",
IF(RIGHT(A5,1)="5", "D","")))))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice breakdown of points. I will propose a different solution, but you have nicely framed the key issues.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a SWITCH to make a clean formula. But as already noted, the last character in ID is text and needs to be compared to text, not numbers.  Here is the SWITCH based solution:

```
=SWITCH(RIGHT(A2,1),
        "1","A","2","A","6","A",
        "3","B","7","B","9","B",
        "4","C","8","C","0","C",
        "5","D",
        "")
```

Comment: I had a translation error in my previous comment and wrote `SWITCH` instead of `CHOOSE`. Sorry! Here's the corrected version: Or even shorter: `=CHOOSE(VALUE(RIGHT(A2;1))+1;"C";"A";"A";"B";"C";"D";"A";"B";"C";"B")`

Comment: I was just typing the same thing!! [@Qualia Well done! That is super clean and easy to understand. But do you mean CHOOSE? e.g.: `=CHOOSE(IFERROR(VALUE(RIGHT(A2,1)),10)+1,"C","A","A","B","C","D","A","B","C","B","")` - but this requires an IFERROR either on the inside or outside to cover the case of VALUE resulting in an error when taking a non-numerical character. In any case, your formula is more readable and shorter.]

Comment: @Qualia - I went for a jog and thought of a way to make your formula even shorter: `=IFERROR(CHOOSE(CODE(RIGHT(A2,1))-47,"C","A","A","B","C","D","A","B","C","B"),"")`. There needs to be a point system for shortest formula. :-D

Comment: A nice one, had not encountered ```SWITCH``` before

Comment: @Euler'sDisgracedStepchild - It's quite like the Switch function in VBA. I rarely put it to use, but when an IF gets complex, it comes in handy. Qualia proposed CHOOSE, which is very similar and would also make sense in this complex situation - in fact, I think it makes even more sense. The tricky part is the else = "" which SWITCH accommodates, but CHOOSE requires some internal or external manipulation. One of the best uses of SWITCH I have ever seen is `SWITCH(TRUE, booleanStatement1, result1, boolStmt2, result2,...)`. It inverts a complex IF statement - super cool.